# EventKit: Implement "share"-feature for EKCalendar (entityTypeReminder)

Tags: xcode, swift, share, eventkit, reminders

Is it possible to implement the "share"-feature for EKCalendar (entityTypeReminder) like it is present in the stock Reminders app? And if yes, how would that work?

Since the feature is present in various third party calendar-apps and Calendars and Reminder-Lists share the same EKCalendar-class, this has to be possible somehow, or not?

Steve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current EventKit provides no API to do this, you would need to use/implement the respective server protocols. That is something like EWS for Exchange or [CalDAV](http://sabre.io/dav/building-a-caldav-client/) for most other servers.

In CalDAV, calendar sharing is an extension. Not all CalDAV servers support it, but iCloud, OSX server and Fruux do. You can find the documentation of the extension over here: [Shared and Published Calendars in CalDAV](https://svn.calendarserver.org/repository/calendarserver/CalendarServer/trunk/doc/Extensions/caldav-sharing.txt).